# How to allow HTML to pass through a set block with Nunjucks

Tags: nunjucks

I'm really excited to see that we can [apply a block assignment for set](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#set) through Nunjucks. What would be the correct way to allow HTML to be passed through this approach?

I want to do the following from my initial nunjucks file:

```html
{% set demoSetBlock %}
<div class="mClass">
  <p>a header value in a nunjucks set block</p>
</div>
{% endset %}
```

I then want to call it into my nunjucks template like so...

```html
{{demoSetBlock}}
```

but...it's printing out the content along with the HTML markup on the web page, just like this...

`<div class="mClass"> <p>a header value in a nunjucks set block</p> </div>`

How can we render this so that it shows it as...

`a header value in a nunjucks set block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the official way of resolving the situation, but what appears to be working for me now is using [|safe](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#safe) as an attribute when the set block is called, like so:

```html
{{demoSetBlock|safe}}
```

as a result, my HTML is perfectly rendered on the browser.

This is helpful in cases

- when I don't want to depend on macros.
- when I want to depend on [set](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#set) as an instrumental component for defining and passing data through various parts of my templates.
- where I have other include files (i.e. `_include-header.njk`, `_include-footer.njk`) that are directly attached to my main template file. I could then use set block for one of these files.